# Extract lines with multiple patterns occuring in one column using awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a quite large text file with genetic data (94,807,000 rows). I want to extract the rows in which specific patterns occur in a specific column. I tried using awk and grep in various ways but did not find a way to get the job done. The file is space-delimited and looks like this:

```
   V1     V2 V3 V4   V5      V6
1: 10 179406  T  . HPGM T,T,T,T
2: 10 179407  T  . HPGM T,T,T,T
3: 10 179408  G  . HPGM G,G,G,G
4: 10 179409  A  . HPGM A,A,A,A
5: 10 179410  A  . HPGM A,A,A,A
6: 10 179411  T  . HPGM T,T,T,T
```

V5 and V6 can have more then the four entries shown here and everything might look pretty weird, like:

```
   V1        V2 V3 V4   V5                    V6
1:  1 158154514  A  . HPGO A,AAAA..204..TTTT,A,A
```

I want to keep the lines where **both** entries for H and P (those are the first two comma-delimited characters in `V6`) are **exactly** either A, C, T or G, so should only have one of those four characters. H and P do not have to have the same character, though.  In `V5` multiple combinations can occur, but all start with `HP`. I am not interested if any or how many entries come afterwards and all rows **do have** entries for H and P, so I do not have to deal with missing entries.

I found some answers that show how to search for multiple patterns using logical or || , some that show how too look in a specific field using `$6 ~ '/A,.'` and how to look for exact matches using `== "pattern"`. However, I did not find answers for combining these things and could not figure it out by myself.  Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you consider an "Entry for H and P". `V5` looks like `HPGM` or `HPGO` are those considered "Entries for H and P"? And how does one tell if those H and P entries are exactly either A,C, T or G? Like all values in V6 can't contain anything other than A, C , T or G values? I think the logic makes perfect sense to you, but it's not explained in a way that someone that is unfamiliar with this genetic data file will understand.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Entries for H and P are the first two characters in column V6. In the upper case (6 rows) everything looks good. However in the lower case (1 row) the entry for P is `AAAA..204..TTTT` - these rows should be excluded. In `V5` multiple combinations can occur, but all start with `HP`. In the end,  all rows should look somewhat like the 6 rows above. I just want to exclude lines that have funny stuff like, for example, the `AAAA..204..TTTT`. More general, the first two comma-delimited positions in V6 should have **exactly one** character that is either A, C, T or G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'split($NF, a, /,/) && a[1] a[2] ~ /^[ACTG]{2}$/' file

1: 10 179406  T  . HPGM T,T,T,T
2: 10 179407  T  . HPGM T,T,T,T
3: 10 179408  G  . HPGM G,G,G,G
4: 10 179409  A  . HPGM A,A,A,A
5: 10 179410  A  . HPGM A,A,A,A
6: 10 179411  T  . HPGM T,T,T,T
```

- `split($NF, a, /,/)` is splitting last column by comma
- `a[1] a[2] ~ /^[ACTG]{2}$/` is using a regex to ensure first and second sub-fields after split are one of `A or C or T or G`